# Convert PDF text to better quality

Tags: pdf

I've a scanned image who's text is *selectable* and *searchable*. In other words it no longer is an image. But the quality of how the text looks is really poor (as if it were a scanned image). Is there a tool I can use to fix this?

Comment: If this is off topic for SO, where do such questions go? There are a zillion SE sites now. I get distracted.

Answer (score 1):

OCR tools often show the bit-map to hide the text they get wrong. What OCR tool did you use?

Comment: Someone gave me the PDF. I don't know what was used, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just try a **Select All** (`Ctrl + A` or similar) and then copy/paste into some kind of tect-based editor (*i.e.* Microsoft Word, Notepad, Emacs... etc).

This will show you the raw text (without the bitmap image) - however, be prepared for OCR errors!